# Auto download file from a link using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I download a file in a link (say: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) using javascript?

Edit: I want to download it automatically without any user interaction. There may be a lots of file. And all of them need to be downloaded on page load.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `download` attribute, and do it without javascript

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" download>download file</a>
```

To make it run without user interaction, you can create the anchor and trigger a click on it with javascript

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
a.download = 'download';

a.click();
```

Comment: Tried the code in the chrome, it still pop up a dialog to prompt user for file name.

Comment: @jay.m - browsers no longer lets you download files without user interaction due to security issues.

Comment: This worked with one change. My web page runs in a sandbox so it seems I have to open a new window first so: `var newWindow=window.open("", '_blank'); var a = newWindow.document.createElement('a');` did it. Unfortunately it does leave a blank window open. if you do `newWindow.close()` it close before the user has a chance to save so nothing happens.