# is it possible automatically download a file by the link in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

lets say i have 1000 link like

```
https://test123.sharepoint.com/teams/TechnicalRecordsManagement/Workshop/2014/578090.pdf
```

is it possible to make automatic download without user interaction due to security issues???

some people says  browsers no longer lets you download files without user interaction due to security issues.

i tried simple ways from here
[Auto download file from a link using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674233/auto-download-file-from-a-link-using-javascript)

Comment: So you think it would be a good idea for somebody to land on a page and have 1000 files automatically downloaded. Well thankfully you cannot do that without some sort of special browser add-on. People have to choose to download files.

Comment: You can click the download button using javascript automatically, but  not recommended.

Comment: `automatic download without user interaction` no

Comment: `lets say i have 1000 link like` ... assuming you want to automate the downloading of such files for your own personal uses, you can do so by `file_get_contents()` without any reliance on a `<a href>` tag.

Comment: @GetSet yes i have my own personal link, i have way like using curl php

Comment: @Tri I will post a solution without curl, shortly

Comment: Hey @Tri did you go with the solution or the curl way?

Answer (score -1):

> lets say i have 1000 link like ... assuming you want to automate the downloading of such files for your own personal uses, you can do so by file_get_contents() without any reliance on a  tag. – GetSet
>
> @GetSet yes i have my own personal link, i have way like using curl php – Tri
>
> @Tri I will post a solution without curl, shortly – GetSet

@Tri. The following grabs the contents of the remote file and saves it to your local drive.

```
    $fileToDownload = "https://dmv.ny.gov/brochure/mv21.pdf";
    $contents = file_get_contents($fileToDownload);
    $f = fopen("mv21.pdf", 'w');
    fwrite($f, $contents);
    fclose($f);
```

Thats the basic concept.

Edited to add context.

Comment: Downvoter, leave your comment on why u think this doesn't work. I tested it before I posted.